# how can i assign multiple cores to every process in my os

Tags: linux, process, centos7, cpu, cpu-cores

I have VM which builds on cantos 7,so I want to make every process in the system to use more than one core in parallel
I have a 24 CPU on my server, but every process can't use more than 1 core, after that the CPU is always 100%. I need to make more utilization of CPU with other cores.

I need to make a huge process to use multipe cores instead of one core?
How can I do such a thing like that?

Comment: Divide into separate processes or threads which don't need to share common data.  Scheduler will run them on different cores or you can use taskset.

Comment: In general, auto-parallelizing a single-threaded program is an unsolved problem.  You generally have to do it manually, or use programming frameworks / languages / libraries that are designed around parallelism.  (e.g. a matrix multiply library that internally uses multiple threads for one big matmul, vs. having separate threads working on totally separate tasks if you parallelize at a higher level).  See [How does a single thread run on multiple cores?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/350024) - it doesn't, each core has some internal parallelism (ILP).